# Ubuntu 23.04 does not recognize RaLink Wifi adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, ralink

**Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870 Wireless Adapter
**

I can't find any recent instructions online to install drivers for this brand new (but apparently older chipset) from Ralink. I bought this recently to bypass the difficulty with Realtek adapters not working after every upgrade to Ubuntu. Now I find that this Ralink doesn't work with 23.04 right out of the box either.

Can someone point me to instructions on how to get this adapter working in 23.04?

```
    lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 148f:2870 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870 Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 048d:5702 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0047 Microsoft Corp. IntelliMouse Explorer 3.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:6364 Alcor Micro Corp. AU6477 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

None of the methods I've found online seem to be of any help. Or they are too old.

Thanks.

**Anyone?** I have zero Wifi indications on the taskbar and even installing the drivers for the RealTek adapter I still have nothing in networking for Wifi. Wifi networks as a selection is shown in the drop down but they are grayed out.

It was days ago when an upgrade to my newly installed 23.04 wiped out most of my apps and installs and took out the once working Ralink settings as well.

**Results of lshw**

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 16
       serial: 18:c0:4d:3f:72:dc
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.5.0-14-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:37 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcd04000-fcd04fff memory:fcd00000-fcd03fff
  *-usb
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT2870 Wireless Adapter
       vendor: Ralink Technology, Corp.
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: wlx7e701174a419
       version: 0.01
       serial: 7e:70:11:74:a4:19
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=6.5.0-14-generic firmware=0.36 link=no maxpower=160mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=IEEE 802.11~~~

**And rfkill**

~~~rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I see the network is somehow attached to Realtek drivers but I don't know how to change that.

According to what I read, I supposed to NOT skip any upgrades. I was at 22.10, and upgraded to 23.04, and ran into this problem PLUS finding all my favorite apps were missing and all my links broken so I've been working for days on that too. Getting a feel for what I have to do with the next upgrade. Just haven't gotten to 23.10 yet as upgrading is always a hassle.

I don't show any error message for any USB device in the dmesg file and I don't have a udev file or folder.

Upgrade to 23.10 had no effect that I can see...

**After many tests** discovered that the brand new Ralink device has an internal electronic issue. Sending back to seller.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 will reach the end of life soon. You may want to try 22.04 LTS, or 23.10.

Comment: What are the outputs of the following `sudo lshw -C network`, and `rfkill list all`? Also look at the following log files: `/var/log/udev`. and `/var/log/dmesg` and see if there are any error messages related to your Ralink WiFi adapter. If you find any lines add them to your question.